# How do I find a specific element using css class but no ID using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have an html code as

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ax" > <p>some text ... </p> </div>
    <div class="ax" > <p>some text ... </p> </div>
    <div class="ax" > <p>some text ... </p> </div>
    <div class="ax" > <p>some text ... </p> </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to check each specific "p" in the div classed "ax" if it has more than 175 characters, if it does, it need to show "read more" text in the end.

My main problem is that I can't use id's because these divs will be auto generated.

Please help.

Comment: Adding the correct tags is a key part of asking a question. If you are looking for a jQuery answer then it is always wise to add that to the tag list :)

Answer (score 1):

Get the text of each paragraph, check the length, and use a condition to return the *"read more"* text

```
$('.ax p').text(function(_, txt) {
   return txt.length > 175 ? txt.slice(0,175) + '... read more ...' : txt;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access each of the `ax'  elements, just do:

```
   $(".ax > p").each( function(index, elem) {
        // elem now is one of the "p" tags with "ax" class elements
        if ( $(elem).html().length > 175 ....

   });
```

the callback will be called for each of the elements found. See: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ax').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('p').text().length > 175){
    //redmore();
  }
});
```